# Tikz or tabular to build up a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

To build up a table like the one from the picture with this weird shape and different line thickness, would you go with `tabular` or with `tikz`?[image]

Comment: That really depends. How flexible are you when it comes down to how the tabular will look in the end? Many would also try to reduce the number of lines and different styles of lines. Is there something you had troubles with with `tabular` and/or TikZ?

Comment: I was trying to get that shape since my CCCC, BBBB and AAA have are long and so on and so force. But I guess that I got obfuscated because there's no need to fully copy whatever table I do when I work on paper.
And That was the problem I was trying to emulate the same weird shape using nodes and lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it need to have “this weird shape” and those “different line thickness[es]”?

I’d go with a simple [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)-powered `tabular` (see also [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs)’ excellent manual).

The second code’s only difference is that it uses `@{}` at the start and end of the column specification to remove the horizontal white-space before the first and after the last column.

If needed one could add additional white-space between `Text 1` and `Text 2` with the `@` specification: `@{\hspace{1.5em}}`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,amssymb}
\newcommand*{\ch}{\checkmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll c ccc}
    \toprule
             &                    & Text 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Text 2} \\ \cmidrule{4-6}
             &                    &        & CCC & BBB &      AAA       \\ \midrule
    Typology & Type A             &        & \ch & \ch &      \ch       \\
             & Type B             & \ch    &     &     &  \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Element A} &        & \ch &     &      \ch       \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Element B} & \ch    &     & \ch &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\par\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll c ccc@{}}
    \toprule
             &                       & Text 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Text 2} \\ \cmidrule{4-6}
             &                       &        & CCC & BBB &      AAA       \\ \midrule
    Typology & Type A                &        & \ch & \ch &      \ch       \\
             & Type B                & \ch    &     &     &  \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Element A} &        & \ch &     &      \ch       \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Element B} & \ch    &     & \ch &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: So the final conclusion is that you would go with tabular and the result is even more elegant.